# Manually Installing Wine-Ubuntu_Vivid_amd64

Tags: wine

I'm trying to manually install `Wine 1.6.2` in Ubuntu 15.04(Vivid). I have the main package: `wine_1.6.2-0ubuntu8.1_amd64.deb` and when I want to install it, it gives error:

```
Dependency not satisfiable: wine1.6
```

Then I down that package and then get another dependency error which leads to another package and then to another which is where I get stuck/(confused)
That one is  The Wine Windows Loader and it says:

```
Dependency not satisfiable: wine1.6-amd64 (=1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8.1)
```

So I already have that package but it throws me back to this package. I know I should use `apt-get update` or `apt-get install` but don't have a connection on this Linux system. So have to do it all manually. Is there someone who has the full working Wine for me? And can you share it so that I can install it manually please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the wine package here to download free. https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu  save to flash install.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't read it all yet but it look like what I'm lookin for. Will comment here when done. Thanks again.